# Why do I get "AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'user' " on some specify url only?

Tags: python, django, login-required

I'm using the @login_required decorator in my project since day one and it's working fine, but for some reason, I'm starting to get "
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'user' " on some specific urls (and those worked in the past).

Example : I am the website, logged, and then I click on link and I'm getting this error that usually is linked to the fact that there is no SessionMiddleware installed. But in my case, there is one since I am logged on the site and the page I am on also had a @login_required.

Any idea?

The url is definied as : `(r'^accept/(?P<token>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?$', 'accept'),`
and the method as : `@login_required
def accept(request,token): ...`

The Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macbook/virtualenv/proj/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 674, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/macbook/virtualenv/proj/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/Users/macbook/virtualenv/proj/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 141, in get_response
    return self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/Users/macbook/virtualenv/proj/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 165, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/Users/macbook/virtualenv/proj/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 100, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/macbook/virtualenv/proj/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 25, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/macbook/dev/pycharm-projects/proj/match/views.py", line 33, in accept
    return __process(token,callback)
  File "/Users/macbook/virtualenv/proj/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 24, in _wrapped_view
    if test_func(request.user):
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'user'`
```

Comment: Can you post the traceback of the AttributeError? It seems that some code is acessing `request.user` when request actually is a unicode object somewhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The decorator was on a private method that doesn't have the request as a parameter. I removed that decorator (left there because of a refactoring and lack of test [bad me]).

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you call a decorated method from another method without providing a request parameter.